# Select Single Element from Cell Array

Tags: matlab

Obviously I could do this with a loop, but I'm wondering if there is a more canonical way of doing this in MATLAB.

Let's say I have a cell array full of structure types (*not* a struct array).  Each structure has an id field.  I would like to find the instance with an id of n. So, replacing this loop with something more "MATLAB-Y":

```
X = % get some cell array
c = repmat(X{1}, 1);
for i = 1:numel(X)
    if X{i}.id == n
        c = X{i};
        break;
    end
end

% use c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your fields are incompartible, use:

```
X{find(cellfun(@(x)(x.('id')==n),X),1,'first')}
```

Otherwise, convert to a struct using:

```
S=[X{:}];
X{find([S.id]==n,1)}
```

Comment: I had looked into using `cellfun`, but I didn't realize that it could be used as a selector.  Thanks.

Comment: On a side note, why not use dynamic field names? `x.('id') == n`

Comment: @EdS.: There is no reason to use getfield here, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The code uses **[`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)** and **[`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html)** and are discussed in comments for the code.

Code -

```
%// First convert the cell array to a numeric array using cell2mat,
%// which will essentially open up the inner struct.
s1 = cell2mat(X)

%// Convert the struct to a cell array using struct2cell such that each row would
%// have data from each of its field -
y1 = struct2cell(s1)
d1 = y1(getfield(s1, 'id'),:) %// Get data from only 'id' field as a cell array

%// Finally try to match n with the values in d1 after converting it to a
%// double array using cell2mat
c = X{find(cell2mat(d1)==n,1)}
```